# Overwrite DLLs that have changed - would this cause DLL Hell?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Say I create a Visual Studio solution with the following projects:

```
'WindowsApp1
    Imports ClassLibrary1
    Imports ClassLibrary2    
    Public Class Form1
        Dim c1 As New ClassLibrary1.Class1
        Dim c2 As New ClassLibrary2.Class1

        Public Sub Form_load() Handles Me.Load
            MsgBox(c1.SayHello)
            MsgBox(c2.SayHello)
        End Sub
    End Class

    'ClassLibrary1
    Public Function SayHello()
        Return "Hello"
    End Function

    'ClassLibrary2
    Public Class Class1
        Public Function SayHello()
            Return "Good Afternoon!"
       End Function
    End Class
```

I publish this by copying the following files to a directory (c:\myapp) on my PC:

```
WindowsApplication1.exe
ClassLibrary1.dll
ClassLibrary2.dll
```

Now, say I wanted to make a change to ClassLibrary1.dll so it contains the following:

```
'ClassLibrary1
        Public Function SayHello()
            Return "Good Morning"
        End Function
```

Can I compile the solution and then simply overwrite c:\myapp\ClassLibrary1.dll with the new version of ClassLibrary1.dll (copied from the solution Release folder)? I have tried this and it appears to work.

Comment: @Hans Passant, why would changing a constant cause a problem?

Answer (score 2):

*True* DLL Hell is only invoked when you update a DLL that is used by more than one application.  Where the update fixes a bug in one app but breaks another.  Not your scenario.

Still, there are some sneaky ways in which a DLL update can appear to modify the behavior of a code in another assembly.  Even though you never changed a source code file that was used to build that assembly.  Evil ones are a Public Const and a default value of an Optional method parameter.  The non-updated assemblies will continue to use the original value since it was compiled into the assembly.  That doesn't often turn out well.

Comment: Thanks+1.  Does this apply to ASP.NET apps as well i.e. stop IIS server, then replace the DLL in the BIN directory and then start IIS?